# Customizing a Joomla submenu

Tags: php, html, joomla

Is it possible to customize a Joomla submenu? This article talks about submenu items: [http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial:Creating_a_submenu](http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial%3aCreating_a_submenu)

What I need to do is create the submenu items with additional DIVs and other HTML elements around them and have them appear elsewhere on the page (not directly under the main menu). In Advanced Module Parameters, you can put "_menu" in Module Class Suffix to add CSS but how do you add DIVs and other HTML elements to create a custom submenu?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Joomla? 1.5 or 1.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[http://www.learnwebdesignonline.com/cms/customizing-joomla-templates.htm][1]

I don't know how much you know about Joomla so I'm gonna start you off with this link to show you where you can access the HTML.

If you use Mozilla Firefox I highly recommend getting an add-on called "Firebug" so you can inspect a website that runs Joomla and has a customized menu with sub-menus to get a glimpse of how the HTML is structured for their menu. If they have what you're looking for.  To have the submenus show up elsewhere on the page it really depends on where you want them to show up.

You may have to setup a menu with submenus on each and every page in the specific sections you need to put them.  However at that point all you have to do is just add the link of where the submenu would take you and place it wherever you want in the page.

Hope this helps but if not could you elaborate on where and how you want to create submenus in separate areas of the page?  I'm a little confused otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can download some menu extension from here: http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=menu .